# Shuffling deck algorith

Tags: java

I have the following java code, which is supposed to "shuffle" cards in a deck. The deck is an arraylist containing card objects.

```
private void ShuffleDeck() {
    //Number of cards in deck
    int deckSize = deck.size();

    //Swapping 100 cards
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        //Generating two random card indexes
        int indexA = (int) ((Math.random() * deckSize-1));
        int indexB = (int) (Math.random() * deckSize-1);
        System.out.println(indexA + " " + indexB);

        //Getting objects
        Card cardA = deck.get(indexA);
        Card cardB = deck.get(indexB);

        //Temporaily removing these cards from deck
        deck.remove(cardA);
        deck.remove(cardB);

        //Swapping around the two cards
        deck.add(indexA, cardB);
        deck.add(indexB, cardA);

    }

}
```

However, when I run this method some cards seem to "disappear" from the deck... Any suggestions as to why this is? :)

Comment: Can you use `Collections.shuffle`?

Comment: Or at least [`Collections.swap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)?

Comment: Are you required to implement everything without the use of other packages/libraries?  I.E. is this an academic exercise?

Comment: Makoto no, it's my personal project, simply I didn't know about the existance of other libraries... I quite new to java :)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `deck` is a `List<Card>` (including `ArrayList`, etc.):

```
public void shuffleDeck() { // please use camelCase method names
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
}
```

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Ok thanks! :D Didn't know about the Collections library :) Also, I have been taught to name variables using camelCase, finals using FULL_UPPERCASE and methods capitalizing every letter (ie: MyOtherMethod): is this wrong? :\

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. Methods should have lowercase start letter. Otherwise it would be Object.HashCode() and Object.Equals() ....

Comment: Class names are PascalCased, method and field names are camelCased, constants are CAPITALIZED_UNDERSCORED.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it the accepted answer by clicking the green check mark.